# Creating a workflow to stop deactivating user linked to a Teritorry

Tags: workflow

I want to create a workflow to stop deactivating a User if he/she is linked to a Territory.

For instance, a CDM who stopped working at my org and I need to create a workflow to stop deactivating him/her if the CDM is linked to Territory.

Could anyone please help me as this is urgent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this requirement via workflow. You have to write down trigger on User object and trigger will fire while user isActive check box will be unchecked. With that particular deactivated user we need to check UserTerritory object whether the user belongs to any territory or not. UserTerritory object is a combination of User and territory. If the user exist in the object with any territory you need to show error via adderror method.

Comment: Hi Avijit, if possible could you please share how to write the trigger? I am new to SFDC. could you please help me out.